# how to rdiff-backup with list increments

Tags: scripting, nfs, command, rdiff-backup

I have already created nfs server and client for backup web server and cms server like at http://www.myee.web.id/2012/04/nfs-server-for-backup/
Then I installed rdiff-backup, for backup I running command like below:

```
   # rdiff-backup --list-increments /app/beta /mnt/nfs/web
```

Then message error occurs.

Question : should I make a script for increment backup with rdiff-backup ? 
Or is it just a wrong command option?

Sorry if any mistake with my asking. 
Thanks before and after.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably getting

```
  Fatal Error: Wrong number of arguments given.
  See the rdiff-backup manual page for more information.
```

It says that `--list-increments` option can only be applied to your destination directory.

First you have to actually backup your data

```
  rdiff-backup /app/beta /mnt/nfs/web
```

After that

```
  rdiff-backup --list-increments /mnt/nfs/web
```

should return

```
  Found 0 increments:
  Current mirror: Wed Apr 25 09:55:39 2012
```

Meaning the backup is up to date.

Please read manual page for `rdiff-backup` to better understand available options.

Comment: I tested, [root@backup ~]# rdiff-backup /root /backup/test/ then [root@backup ~]# rdiff-backup --list-increments /root /backup/test/
Fatal Error: Wrong number of arguments given.
See the rdiff-backup manual page for more information.

Comment: Try testing `# rdiff-backup --list-increments /backup/test`
i.e. omitting `/root`

Comment: What different are ?
Thanks

Comment: --list-increments requires only one path as an argument